# I did not find the generate namespace in The Console Component in symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, console, generate

I keep rereading the symfony 4  documentation to try to generate controller with the  console commands and  when  I list The Console commands  in symfony 4 I did not  find the generate namespace  . is there any one know how to add generate namespace to the  console commands in  symfony 4 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the generate namespace"? That's just creating a folder at the proper place...

Comment: I mean that  i did not  find  the  generate:controller in  the  consol comands  in  symfony 4 when I run the command  php bin\console  in the list of  commands i  did  not  find  the  generate:controller  command  but  i see  it when i run php bin\console in symfony2 or  symfony3 project

Answer (score 0):

"generate:controller" is a feature of the SensioGeneratorBundle which is not compatible with Symfony 4. You have to install the [Maker Bundle](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle) and use it's command "make:controller" instead